# Bug in AssociationField with autocomplete() for Many to Many field in EasyAdmin

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, easyadmin, easyadmin3

I have an entity called `Question` which has a **Many to Many** relationship with another entity `User`. So I have following tables:

```
question(id, field1, users)
user(id, name)
question_user(question_id, user_id)
```

I use EasyAdmin for creating QuestionCrud form where I use `AssociationField` for assigning multiple Users to a Question. If I use `AssociationField` without `autocomplete()` method it works like a charm and stores the data. But I have really big amount of data in User table and that's why need to use autocomplete in order to load only small amount of data.

Using `autocomplete()` with `AssociationField` giving following error and giving validation error on a form submit:

```
The choices 123, 2323 do not exist in the choice list.
```

123, 2323 are IDs of the selected users.

Has anybody faced such a problem?

Comment: Can we see your whole field configuration

Comment: This one works: 
yield AssociationField::new('users')->setFormTypeOption('by_reference', false)
This one DOESN'T:
yield AssociationField::new('users')->setFormTypeOption('by_reference', false)->autocomplete()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A month ago another developer faced the same problem - https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/5467. He proposed to edit vendor file `src/Form/EventListener/CrudAutocompleteSubscriber.php` and thanks to his investigation on what was wrong with autocomplete() method on many-to-many relationship we came out with another solution.

Instead of editing a vendor file we decided to override `findBy` method of the Entity repository.

```
public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
{
    if (isset($criteria['id']) && is_array($criteria['id'])) {
        $ids = [];
        foreach ($criteria['id'] as $id) {
            if (Uuid::isValid($id)) {
                $ids[] = Uuid::fromString($id)->toBinary();
            } else {
                $ids[] = $id;
            }
        }
        $criteria['id'] = $ids;
    }

    return parent::findBy($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset);
}
```

This solution is good as far as you have only one Entity which is used as many-to-many relationship, but if there are several entities, then the `findBy` method should be overridden in all of them.

Hope that supporters of EasyAdmin will fix this bug soon and we will not need to use such 'ugly' solutions.